# Output Image from ACF options field

Tags: twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

How can I output an image from the ACF options field with Timber/Twig?

Below is what I have now, but unfortunately it isn't working. I just can't get it done. What am I doing wrong?

**Timber controller**

```
$context['theme_options'] = get_fields('options');
```

**Twig file**

```
<img src="{{ Image(options.footer_logo).src }}" />
```

Comment: For starters, the variable you are passing is `theme_options`, yet you are using `options` in the template

Comment: Thank you for your help. That is indeed the solution. I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee) mentioned in a [comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73574365/output-image-from-acf-options-field#comment129931431_73574365), you’re using `options` instead of `theme_options` in your Twig file. Try using this:

**Twig file**

```
<img src="{{ Image(theme_options.footer_logo).src }}" />
```

The rest seems to be looking good.

In case you want to check what’s inside `theme_options` in Twig, you can use the `dump()` function:

```
{{ dump(theme_options) }}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help. That is indeed the solution. I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

**Twig File:**

```
<img src="{{ Image(options.footer_logo).src }}"  alt="{{ Image(options.footer_logo).alt }}"/>
```

This code is accessible without adding any code to the timber controller.

If you want to add specifically inside the timer controller for options page acf then use context variable in the twig file likes so:

**Timber Controller:**

```
$context['theme_options'] = get_fields('options');
```

**Twig File:**

```
<img src="{{ Image(theme_options.footer_logo).src }}" alt="{{ Image(theme_options.footer_logo).alt }}"/>
```

For more information use this link below:
[Timber Documentation for Options Page with Advance Custom Field](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#options-page)